# C# Textbox Focus

Tags: c#, windows, tabs, key

In a windows form c# application I have two Textbox Control.

I setup tabindex 1 into first control
I setup tabindex 2 into secondo control

When I press tab in the first control, I need to do some check operation.

I try to intercept the tab key, with this code

```
control1__KeyPress(...)
{
   if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Tab)
    {
     ....
    }
}
```

but the event is not fired.

I try to do it into

```
control1__KeyDown(...)
{

}
```

but the event is also not fired.

How I can intercept the tab key before the second control have the focus?

Thanks

Comment: If you are validating the input then there is the appropriate event Validating, if you want act on lost focus (whatever the way the control loose the focus) then there is the Leave event.

Comment: The Tab key is used for navigation, you'll never get it in the KeyDown or KeyPress event.  You almost certainly want to subscribe the control's Validating event instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have said in my comment, you should use the appropriate event handler depending on what are your requirements. There is a [Validating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx) event that could help if your intent is just to validate user input. There is a [Leave](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave(v=vs.110).aspx) event if your intent is to be alerted when a control loose focus.

If you really want just process the TAB key then you should resort to overriding the [ProcessCmdKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx) as in this example

```
public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData )
    {
        if( keyData == Keys.Tab)
        {
            // This method will be called for every control in your form
            // so probably you need to add some checking on the Handle
            // of the control that originates the call
            if(msg.Hwnd == yourTextBox.Handle)
            {
                 ExecuteYourTabProcessinLogicHere();

                 // Returning TRUE here halts the normal behavior of the 
                 // TAB key, you could change this based on the result 
                 // of your logic
                 return true; 
            }
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

However, I should warn you that messing with the TAB key could be very unsettling for your users that expects this key to have a well predefined behavior